# how to read an array that has lots of nested entity

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I'm a newbie PHP programmer. I met a problem today. here the thing.

I have an array like this

```
$array = array( "id" => 1,
                "region"=>"world", 
                "parentid" => 0, 
                "children" => array("id" => 39, 
                                    "region"=>"asia",
                                    "parentid" => 1, 
                                    "children" => array("id" => 70, 
                                                        "region"=>"china",
                                                        "parentid" => 39
                                                        )
                                )
            );
```

I want to get some result like this structrue.

```
world
  |-  asia
  |-----  china
```

here is my code ,It looks very bad even though it works. but it wouldn't work well when the level more than 3.

```
$array = array();
$count = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dep); $i++) {
$array[]["region"] = $dep[$i]["region"];
if (isset($dep[$i]["children"])) {
    for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($dep[$i]["children"]); $ii++) {
        $array[]["region"] = $dep[$i]["children"][$ii]["region"];
        if (isset($dep[$i]["children"][$ii]["children"])) {
            for ($iii = 0; $iii < count($dep[$i]["children"][$ii]["children"]); $iii++) {
                $array[]["region"] = $dep[$i]["children"][$ii]["children"][$iii]["region"];
            }
        }
    }
}
}

return $array;
```

There must be some better solution to solve the problem. Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: You probably want to write a recursive function for this.

Comment: you have to write a recursive function.

Comment: Look at some link which will give you some idea how to write recursive function

[https://www.copterlabs.com/build-menu-with-recursive-functions/]

[http://lornajane.net/posts/2012/php-recursive-function-example-factorial-numbers]

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage recursion. That means a function that calls itself. Let me paste here a function:

```
$array = [
  [
    "region" => "world",
    "children" => [
      [
        "region"=> "asia",
        "children" => [
          [ "region"=> "china" ],
        ]
      ],
      [
        "region"=> "europe",
        "children" => [
          [ "region"=>"czech republic" ],
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
];


function format($dataset, $prefix = '')
{
  foreach ($dataset as $data) {
    echo $prefix . ' ' . $data['region'] . '<br>';

    if (! isset($data['children'])) {
      return;
    }

    format($data['children'], $prefix . '--');
  }
}

format($array);
```

You have to change up the structure of the array a bit but the function is much more simple. Also the `id` and `parent` keys become redundant.

Comment: Thank you I tried the code but it wouldn't work well. it echo like this:   

    world
-

other regions disappeared.